# Linq get records based by in clause and sort by

Tags: linq

I have persisted a sorted list of ids into the database.  Now i want to get the records back based on the persisted id's.

However, the records are coming back in the order of the primary keys not the order of the int[] which I have persisted.  Not quite sure how this can be acheived.

I currently have the following:

```
int[] ids = {8, 1, 5};

var items = from i in ContentPage.All()
            where ids.Contains(i.ContentPageId)
            select i;
```

Currently the records are coming out in the order of 1, 5, 8 where I actually want 8,1,5

Comment: I suspect it will be tricky to do this in the database... but you can do it when you've received the result. You could even just call `ToDictionary(i => i.ContentPageId)` so you could access by page number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database does not obliged to return items in certain order. You can then process them this way:

```
int[] ids = {8, 1, 5};
var items = (from i in ContentPage.All()
            where ids.Contains(i.ContentPageId)
            select i).ToList();

var answer = (from id in ids
             join item in items
             on id equals item.ContentPageId
             select item).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks!  Was there any reason you converted the int[] array to a list?  It seems to work without doing this?

Comment: This is just overcautious, I returned it back :)